# Getting the Xamarin iOS Google Mobile Ads (Admob) component to work in distribution builds

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, admob, nslayoutconstraint

I used the Xamarin iOS Google Mobile Ads component https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleiosmobileads to put Admob ads into my Xamarin iOS app. I found that to get my app to build, I had to put the following into "additional mtouch arguments" under IOS build options in my iOS project:

```
-framework QuartzCore
```

After I do that, when I run the app on my development device using Xamarin Studio on my Mac, everything works fine. But when I build using a distribution build and submit to the store, no ads appear on devices running iOS 9.

Has anyone else had this problem? If so, were you able to solve it?

I suspect my code is not particularly relevant. But just in case, here is how I create the banner:

```
    private BannerView _Banner {get;set;}

    private UIViewController RootViewController {get;set;} // has been set by the time CreateBanner() is called

    private void CreateBanner() {
      AdSize size = AdSizeCons.SmartBannerPortrait;
      CGPoint origin = new CGPoint();
      _Banner = new BannerView(size, origin);
      _Banner.AdUnitID = this.AdUnitID;
      _Banner.RootViewController = this.RootViewController;
      _Banner.AdReceived += this.AdReceived;
      _Banner.ReceiveAdFailed += this.AdFailed;
      Request request = Request.GetDefaultRequest();
      _Banner.LoadRequest(request);
    }

     private bool _Loaded {get;set;}
     public void AdReceived(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       this._Loaded = true;
       NotifyAdWrapperView(); // code not shown; shows/hides the ad.
     }
     public void AdFailed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       this._Loaded = false;
       NotifyAdWrapperView(); // code not shown
     }
```

EDIT: I notice the following in the device console when running the distribution build, but not when running the debug build. Interestingly, a little googling reveals cases of people seeing layout constraint errors in iOS 9 that they didn't see before.

```
Apr 21 13:43:15 Williams-iPad MyAppName[206] <Warning>: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
        Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
        Try this: 
            (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
            (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x12fd836d0 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x12fe9db90]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x12fd81d40 )>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x12fe9eea0 'UIInputWindowController-top' V:|-(0)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x12fe9db90]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x12fd81d40 )>"
```

Comment: This may have simply been a coding bug I had that only manifested itself in release mode and was unrelated to the component.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Linker settings to `Link Framework SDKs Only` on Release:

[image]

Comment: That is the setting I have, yes. FWIW, based on the reviews of that Xamarin component, it seems I'm not the only person to have a problem of the ads not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Could be fixed in version 7.7.1.1:
https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleiosmobileads

> Version 7.7.1.1
>
> ```
> Changed SearchRequest BaseType from NSObject to Request class (This fix issue #5)
> Added missing Fluid AdSize constant
> ```